# How to gnu parallel this script that counts non-numerics appearing in CSV file columns

Tags: bash, csv, gnu-parallel

My attempts to make the following script parallel have failed. What is the trick here?  This script works on one column of the file at a time.  I would like to process many columns in parallel.

Here is the sequential script. It returns value 1 correctly, because that is how many nonnumeric are in column 11 of the CSV file:

```
$ tail -n +2 beerdirty.csv | cut -d, -f 11 | awk -F"," '(($1+0 != $1) && ($1!="")){cnt++} END{print cnt+0}'
1
```

Here is my failed attempt at gnu parallel. I just want the integer from seq to go into the cut -f parameter.  Maybe it has a problem with quote chars:

```
$ seq 1 12 | parallel 'tail -n +2 beerdirty.csv | cut -d, -f {} | awk -F"," "(($1+0 != $1) && ($1!="")){cnt++} END{print cnt+0}"'
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near )
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near )
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near )
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near )
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near )
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near )
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near )
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near )
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near )
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near )
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near )
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near )
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested:

```
doit() {
  tail -n +2 beerdirty.csv |
  cut -d, -f $1 |
  awk -F"," '(($1+0 != $1) && ($1!="")){cnt++} END{print cnt+0}'
}
export -f doit
seq 1 12 | parallel doit
```

Comment: Well I tested it. This works wonderfully.  Thank you again. Now I will study this to see what I missed.